# Asterisk queue agi script set variable problem

Tags: linux, asterisk, queue, agent

ive setup asterisk with queues (agent.conf sip.conf queues.conf)
Everything is working well.

I need to send caller's id to agent's machine (or web site) from queue.

something like this

....
exten => _200,n,Queue(qtest,t,,,10,"test.pl,${MEMBERNAME},${QUEUENAME}")

MEMBERNAME and QUEUENAME are enabled by setinterfacevar=yes in queues.conf
This doesnt work :(. and i cant get that variables in agi script.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very strange. Ive checked version 1.4.x, 1.6.x and 1.8.x and only one solution that was working everywhere was using macros.

like this:

```
extensions.conf
[macro-mymacro]
exten => s,1,NoOp(${MEMBERINTERFACE})

[queue]
exten => s,1,Queue(queue)

queues.conf
setinterfacevar=yes
membermacro=mymacro
```

This macro will be executed right after agent will receive call. This helped me to solve the problem. I also can agi from macro